# Android: Data Binding: providing values in included layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-include

I have the following layout - text_input_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="textType" type="String"/>
    </data>
    <TextInputLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
      android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/White"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="@{textType}"
            android:id="@+id/password" />
    </TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

I would like to include this layout in another layout but change the inputType to textPassword, textEmail etc depending on the requirement.

```
<layout xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <include layout="@layout/text_input_layout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:textType="textPassword"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I tried to use data binding but it does not seem to work. Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see answer. It would help you.

Answer (score 2):

> `textPassword` is not a String. It is an **`attribute`** so you can
>   not pass it like `app:textType="textPassword"`. `app:textType` accept integer value.

**Solution**

1) Take `textType` as `Integer` value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="textType"
            type="Integer"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="@{textType}"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

2) Pass `Integer` to `<include` tag `app:textType`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.text.InputType"/>

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <include
            layout="@layout/sample"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:textType="@{(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)}"
            />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**You can also pass 1,2,3... without importing `InputType` but that should be valid `InputType`**.

```
int TYPE_CLASS_TEXT = 1;
int TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD = 128;
```

Comment: just an update to your answer - it has to be `bind:textType:` now